# In Linux CI (Jenkins) system, build Xcode project without using physical Mac OS machine

Tags: xcode, docker, continuous-integration, virtual-machine

In Linux CI (Jenkins) system, I want to build Xcode project without using physical Mac OS machine. 
1.)Please give me best options?
2.)Can I use Docker (with latest Xcode version)?

What is the best option to build Xcode project without using physical Mac OS machine in Linux CI (Jenkins) system? 
Can I use Docker or VM?

Answer (score 1):

You can not build Xcode project without MacOs 
the only way to have build of that project is to have a slave for your Linux Ci working on Mac Os machine